# Page current stdout to less, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a snippet like this:

```
my_string = "foo bar"
def print_string(fd=sys.stdout):
    print(my_string, file=fd)
```

How do I get to pipe the output of `print_string` to a pager, say, `less`?

I'm aware of using `subprocess.Popen` with `stdin=PIPE`, and then using `proc.communicate()`, but then I can only write `my_string` directly, not redirect from an existing descriptor.

Although a bit silly, but I tried the below; I'm not surprised that it doesn't work:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("less -".split(), stdin=sys.stdout)
print_string()
proc.wait()
```

Git commands seems to do the same thing, effectively: pipes its output through a pager; and I was trying to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 2):

Less needs to read from the "real" stdin to get key presses, otherwise it can't react to user input. Instead you can create a temporary file and let less read that:

```
import subprocess
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w") as f:
    f.write("hello world!")
    f.flush() // flush or otherwise the content 
              // might not be written when less tries to read
    p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/less", f.name])
    p.wait()
```

This might have security consequences, best to read the documentation on tempfile before using it on something super secure.

I'm also not sure how git does it or if there is a better way, but it worked in my short tests.

Comment: I did think about such an approach. Any thoughts about how Git does it? (Of course I can dig into the source, but such a bother...).

Comment: I'm not so sure anymore about less needing stdin, when usinig `cat text | less` less also reads from the "pipe stdin" and from the terminal.. maybe someone knows more. [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/pydoc.py#l1450) is a implementation with pipes. Maybe you could simply use `pydoc.pager`.